# I Want TO Get Color When I Call Widget

Tags: flutter, send

I Create A ListView in Another File I Want To Call List View but with this i want to send a color in List View File When I Call List View How can i do this?

This is List View Code >

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListViewFromApi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListViewFromApiState createState() => _ListViewFromApiState();
}

class _ListViewFromApiState extends State<ListViewFromApi> {
  var data;
  var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    var res = await http.get(url);
    data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: data != null
            ? ListView.builder(
                // itemCount: 6,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Card(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                      elevation: 50,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/icons/avatar.png",
                                  height: 45,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      'Muhammad Anus',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '10/17/2020',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
                              color: Colors.purple,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    data[index]["title"],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Image.asset(
                                "assets/icons/dil.png",
                                height: 30,
                              ),
                              Image.asset(
                                "assets/icons/copy.png",
                                height: 25,
                              ),
                              Image.asset(
                                "assets/icons/whatsapp.png",
                                height: 35,
                              ),
                              Image.asset(
                                "assets/icons/share.png",
                                height: 25,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ));
  }
}
```

This is Home File Where i want to call list view with color >

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../bottom_nav.dart';
import 'components/Drawer.dart';
import 'components/list_view.dart';
// import 'package:saasti_shayari/screens/home_screen/components/body.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class Home_Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Home_ScreenState createState() => _Home_ScreenState();
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _Home_ScreenState extends State<Home_Screen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Home",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: "google_fonts/Title.ttf",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListViewFromApi(),

          > Here I Want to send color from this file to another file with this List With
            i am begineer in flutter please help me

      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

> How can i do this please guide me When i Call ListView Widget From HomeScreen i want to send color from home screen to listView screen how i do this?

Comment: Are you getting any List of Colors from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a constructor for ListViewFormApi class with a color property:

```
class ListViewFromApi extends StatefulWidget {
  
  Color color;
  ListViewFromApi({this.color});
  
  @override
  _ListViewFromApiState createState() => _ListViewFromApiState();
}
```

When you make a call to ListViewFromApi you need to do it as :

```
body: ListViewFromApi(color : Colors.blue),
```